# How do I setup TagLib 1.11.1 as a static library for my Qt Creator project on OS X?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, taglib, .a

I am working on a C++ project in Qt Creator (on OS X), and I want to use TagLib. After much research online, I'm struggling to figure out how to get to a point where I can use the TagLib library in my project.

So far I have:

- Downloaded `taglib-1.11.1.tar` and unarchived the contents.
- Downloaded CMake and used the GUI to *configure* and *generate* these files. (I used the CodeBlocks - Unix options for this, as from what I have found this has been suggested)
- From here I have tried: **a)** Adding the generated files as an external library to my Qt Creator Project. However, this seems to just add ~ 3 lines to my current .pro file referencing the path of the TagLib files. **b)** Creating a new project specifically for this library... **c)** smashing my head against the wall trying to get this to work.

Any help with this would be much appreciated, thanks.

**Edit:**

When I add the external library, the following is added to my .pro file:

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -     L$$PWD/../../../Libraries/taglib-1.11.1/taglib/release/ -ltag
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../Libraries/taglib-1.11.1/taglib/debug/ -ltag
else:mac: LIBS += -F$$PWD/../../../Libraries/taglib-1.11.1/taglib/ -framework tag
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../Libraries/taglib-1.11.1/taglib/ -ltag

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../Libraries/taglib-1.11.1/taglib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../Libraries/taglib-1.11.1/taglib
```

I then run qmake, and the project builds & runs fine. However, if I attempt to do something like `#include <tag.h>`, I get an error. For this example, it says `'tstring.h' file not found #include "tstring.h"`. Then, when I delete the error line, it gives a different error when I run it `framework not found tag` `linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`.

**Edit:**

code in .pro changed to:

```
#win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../Libraries/taglib-1.11.1/taglib/release/ -ltag
#else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../Libraries/taglib-1.11.1/taglib/debug/ -ltag
LIBS += -F$$PWD/../../../Libraries/taglib-1.11.1/taglib/ -ltag
#else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../Libraries/taglib-1.11.1/taglib/ -ltag

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../Libraries/taglib-1.11.1/taglib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../Libraries/taglib-1.11.1/taglib
```

Now I get the error `library not found for -ltag`.

Here is an image of the files under `../Libraries/taglib-1.11.1` and the options I used in CMake [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LM8hW.jpg).

**Edit:**

I installed in it using the following:

```
  cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
  make
  sudo make install
```

Now the directory of files in the library looks like the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7HDJ.jpg). Then I re-added the external directory in Qt. So now my .pro file contains:

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../Libraries/taglib-1.11.1/taglib/ -ltag

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../Libraries/taglib-1.11.1/taglib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../Libraries/taglib-1.11.1/taglib

PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../Libraries/taglib-1.11.1/taglib/libtag.a
```

Now it runs fine, unless I try to do something like `#include <tag.h>` and it gives the error `'tstring.h' file not found`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only build taglib without installing it.

You should have something along the lines of:

```
INCLUDEPATH += \
    /path/to/taglib_source/taglib \
    /path/to/taglib_source/taglib/toolkit \
    /path/to/taglib_builddir/

LIBS += \
    -L/path/to/taglib_builddir/taglib \
    -ltag
```

If you installed taglib using the defaults:

```
INCLUDEPATH += \
    /usr/local/include/taglib

LIBS += \
    -L/usr/local/lib \
    -ltag
```

Comment: Remove the `else:mac` clause, you don't get a framework when building taglib but a classic library. Note that this isn't a bug, most of the time macOS development stuff comes in bundle called Frameworks.

Comment: I made the change you suggested, but I run in to a different error. I addressed it in an edit. Thanks

Comment: Did you install taglib after building it ? My current proposition is if you use it from source/build folder. Otherwise you should update your paths to where you installed it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'install' taglib?

Comment: call `make install` after you built taglib

Comment: I have now installed the library. Thank you for that. But, it still gives an error when trying to `#include` something from taglib. ( I made an edit in the post )

Comment: Remove the current code generated. Since you installed it, you should follow my second .pro file example or  and got get taglib where you installed it (`/usr/local`) otherwise, you have to add the additional includes from my first .pro file example.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I've managed to get it working. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Doing this with Cmake:**

CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory ("[path]/taglib")
add_library(taglib STATIC) # use SHARED for dynamic linking
```

[ lots of code ...]
[After `add_executable(...)`]

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    [optionally other libs]
    # id3 tags
    taglib
)
```