# include TagLib as static library with cmake (Qt Project)

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I want to use the [TagLib](https://taglib.org/) library in a c++/qt project with cmake and mingw!

1. I have downloaded the taglib 1.12 source files
2. I have build it with mingw (cmake Gui) with static parameters (-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DENABLE_STATIC_RUNTIME=ON)
3. I have also installed it `mingw32-make install`

Now I am unsure how to include the library.

- what files I have to include?

After some experiments theses are the parts from the CMakeLists file:

```
add_library(tag STATIC IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(tag PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/taglib_build/taglib/libtag.a" <- from build
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/taglib/include/taglib" <- from install
)

target_link_libraries(Project PRIVATE tag)
```

Now if I include eg. `#include <taglib.h>` an error pops up:

```
Example.cpp:65: Fehler: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN6TagLib8FileNameC1EPKc'
```

There have been some similar questions, but I cannot make it work.

[Compiling static TagLib 1.6.3 libraries for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878883/compiling-static-taglib-1-6-3-libraries-for-windows)

[How do I setup TagLib 1.11.1 as a static library for my Qt Creator project on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41817653/how-do-i-setup-taglib-1-11-1-as-a-static-library-for-my-qt-creator-project-on-os/73258117#73258117)

Please, can someone help?